# Is there an inventory?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Is there an inventory where I can see the items I have picked up/bought during my journey, that I haven't used and are still carrying around?

Comment: What can you own besides weapons?

Comment: I think he's referring to a complete list of Mods he may have, or special items like Wine etc., or even the artifacts he may have picked up from missions/scans.

Comment: @fredley i was referring to the items that Pithlit mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That, would be a useful feature, but alas no.

You can view weapons and upgrades at a weapon upgrade bench, and you can view armor parts at an armor station.

There is no inventory that displays everything or even just quest items.  It's very annoying in that respect.

Comment: That is to bad, I was hopping there was a list of quest items

Comment: @Blem yeah, managing quests is a nightmare in ME3. That's part of why we have so many questions :)

Comment: I was disappointed when I saw that the objectives in the journal don't update as you progressed on a quest.  In previous games they used to tell you what you had to do next.